# Problem in Intel software Installation

Tags: installation

I try to install Intel parallel_studio_xe_2013_update4 on Ubuntu 12.04.
After activating product key successfully, I received the following error during the installation:

```
The following required for installation commands are missing: g++
```

Can any one assist me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question. You must to install [**g++** (the GNU C++ compiler) [image: Install g++]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/g++/) first.

To install g++ package from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: Command to install g++ ???